# How to show image when textfield is empty only?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage, textfield

i have 4 textfields, a button and an image, what i'm trying to achieve is that when the button is pressed it should warn the user there are empty textfields and show the image pointing to the empty textfield(s), but make the image disappear when the user put text into the empty textfield. Thank you

here is my func

```
func checkFields(){
    let userEmail = user_EmailTxtField.text!
    let userPassword = user_PassTxtField.text!
    let passwordConfirm = pass_ConfirmTxtField.text!
    let userPhone = user_PhoneTxtField.text!
    //Set backArrow image to show input error to password
    let imageName = "backArrow.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let passImageView1 = UIImageView(image: image!)
    passImageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 319, y: 331, width: 49, height: 49)
    view.addSubview(passImageView1)
    //Show Arrow image to password confirm error
    let passConfirmImageView1 = UIImageView(image: image!)
    passConfirmImageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 319, y: 394, width: 49, height: 49)
    view.addSubview(passConfirmImageView1)
    //Show arrow Image to email error
    let emailImageView1 = UIImageView(image: image!)
    emailImageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 319, y: 270, width: 49, height: 49)
    view.addSubview(emailImageView1)
    //Set image to phonetxt field error
    let phoneImageView1 = UIImageView(image: image!)
    phoneImageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 319, y: 209, width: 49, height: 49)
    view.addSubview(phoneImageView1)
    if userPhone.isEmpty {
        phoneImageView1.isHidden = false
    } else {
        phoneImageView1.isHidden = true
    }
    if userEmail.isEmpty {
        emailImageView1.isHidden = false
    }
    if userPassword.isEmpty {
        passImageView1.isHidden = false
    }
    if passwordConfirm.isEmpty {
        passConfirmImageView1.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function where you handle your check and then hide your image if the text isn't empty like this:

**1** Add a target to your textFields at the place where you create them for the event `.editingChanged`:

```
user_EmailTxtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
user_PhoneTxtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
pass_ConfirmTxtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
pass_ConfirmTxtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
```

**2** Setup the method you use to check if the textfields getting edited:

```
func textFieldDidChange() {
  emailImageView1.isHidden = user_EmailTxtField.hasText
  phoneImageView1.isHidden = user_PhoneTxtField.hasText
  passImageView1.isHidden = pass_ConfirmTxtField.hasText
  passConfirmImageView1.isHidden = pass_ConfirmTxtField.hasText
}
```

So if you apply this example to all your text fields you don't need the checks in `checkFields()` and you can rename your the method to `setupTextFields()` for example to use it only as creation of the text fields

Example to use your image views in all methods over the class, but be sure to initialize in `viewDidLoad()` for example to avoid found nil errors while unwrapping an optional value

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {

  // ImageView Reference
  var emailImageView1: UIImageView!

  // then your checkFields method
  func checkFields() {
    // code before
    emailImageView1 = UIImageView(image: image!)
    // code after
  }
}
```

Comment: i've tried this but it give me an error saying "cannot call value of non-function type 'bool' on the textInput.isempty line

Comment: Can you check if you used my latest update of the answer. Updated it quite a lot

Comment: @SCS you can check if your `if !user_EmailTxtField.hasText` even better `emailImageView1.isHidden = user_EmailTxtField.hasText`

Comment: ok, you need to create references for your image views which you show and hide. For example `var emailImageView1: UIImageView!` outside of your `checkFields()` method to access it in the `textFieldDidChange()`method and then you initialize it like `emailImageView1 = UIImageView(image: image!)` without the `let` keyword

Comment: Updated my answer @SCS

Comment: @ronatory i seriously don't understand what is going on, now is telling me "use of unresolved indentifier 'emailImageView1'

Answer (score 0):

you should separate the creation of the image (addSubview) and the check

put the creation to `viewDidLoad`

and later check the fields and hide it or show it.

just now you create each time a new image which is placed over the previous created images (you can check this if you switch to a wireframe 3d debug view)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `if userPhone.isEmpty`, you should try:

```
if user_EmailTxtField.text == nil {
    phoneImageView1.isHidden = false
}
```

You could even do:

```
if user_EmailTxtField.text == nil || user_EmailTxtField.text == "" {
        phoneImageView1.isHidden = false
}
```